# Unmarshall only approved fields

Tags: json, go, reflection, unmarshalling

I'm trying to give permissions to users to edit certain fields of a struct.
This fields will vary depending on the action, the context, and the role the current user has.

At the moment I'm doing this in an imperative way but it's rather tedious and not scalable.

I thought having a list of `approved_fields` could be a nice and more scalable solution but I have no idea how to go through with this. I think reflection is the way to go but I don't know enough yet.

Any inspiration would help.

```
type Foo struct {
  Bar1 int
  Bar2 int
  Bar3 int
}

foo := Foo{}
approved_fields := []string{"Bar1", "Bar2"}
decode(json_data, &foo, approved_fields)

foo2 := Foo{}
approved_fields := []string{"Bar1", "Bar3"}
decode(json_data, &foo2, approved_fields)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would think about solving it. There may be something more efficient since I am unmarshalling the whole item before selectively choosing fields.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func fieldByName(s string, v interface{}) (reflect.Value, error) {
    el := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    fbn := el.FieldByName(s)
    if !fbn.IsValid() {
        return fbn, errors.Errorf("does not have field named %s", s)
    }
    return fbn, nil
}

func decode(data []byte, v interface{}, approvedFields []string) error {
    typeOf := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if typeOf.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        typeOf = typeOf.Elem()
    }
    if typeOf.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        return errors.New("does not support slices")
    }

    newItem := reflect.New(typeOf)
    newItemInterface := newItem.Interface()
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &newItemInterface); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "json unmarshall")
    }
    for _, approvedField := range approvedFields {
        fbn, err := fieldByName(approvedField, v)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, "field by name")
        }
        val, _ := fieldByName(approvedField, newItemInterface)
        fbn.Set(val)
    }
    return nil
}
```

a test:

```
func TestBar1Bar2(t *testing.T) {
    var json_data []byte
    {
        f := &Foo{
            Bar1: 1,
            Bar2: 2,
            Bar3: 3,
        }
        json_data, _ = json.Marshal(f)
    }
    approved_fields := []string{"Bar1", "Bar2"}
    f := &Foo{}
    err := decode(json_data, f, approved_fields)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    assert.Equal(t, f.Bar1, 1)
    assert.Equal(t, f.Bar2, 2)
    assert.Equal(t, f.Bar3, 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this helps a lot, I'm also looking at a strategy where I declare an intermediate type with only the parameters allowed and then do a deep copy. This would help for slices and nested structs.
What do you think?

Comment: "declare an intermediate type with only parameters allowed" you would have to declare every variation of type you would need before compilation. right? My solution could be reworked to use slices pretty easily. Nested structs should also be possible. Just a matter of how you structure the syntax of your approved fields. e.g `"Bar1.Field1"` to access fields of a nested struct. I'd go that route so you could decouple your approved_fields from the app (put them into a database with user groups and permissions)